# Identifing number of character/digits/special character in string

Tags: c#, string

I want to calculate the summary of string in terms of number of alphabets, digits and special character in C#. For example:

> String **abc123$%** should have summary like **A3D3S2** (which means 3 Alphabet, 3 Digits and 2 Special character)
>
> **a34=$@** should have summary like **A1D2S3** (which means 1 Alphabet, 2 Digits and 3 Special character)
>
> **a3b$s** should have summary like **A1D1A1S1A1** (which means 1 Alphabet, 1 Digits,1 Alphabet, 1 Special character,1 Alphabet)

Can anyone guide me how can write an algorithm which can perform the above task in a quick way? as I think if I search the string character by character, then it will take considerable amount of time. and I have a large dataset of strings.

Comment: but I have to maintain the order of the summary string, I have edited my question and added another example to be clear

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works:

```
    static string GetSummary(string input)
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();

        string prevMode = "";
        string curMode = "";
        int sameModeCount = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i <= input.Length; ++i)
        {
            if (i < input.Length)
            {
                char c = input[i];
                if ('a' <= c && c <= 'z' || 'A' <= c && c <= 'Z')
                {
                    curMode = "A";
                }
                else if ('0' <= c && c <= '9')
                {
                    curMode = "D";
                }
                else
                {
                    curMode = "S";
                }
            }
            else
            {
                curMode = "";
            }

            if (curMode != prevMode && prevMode != "")
            {
                sb.Append(prevMode);
                sb.Append(sameModeCount);

                sameModeCount = 0;
            }

            prevMode = curMode;
            ++sameModeCount;
        }

        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

Test:

```
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(GetSummary("abc123$%"));
        Console.WriteLine(GetSummary("a34=$@"));
        Console.WriteLine(GetSummary("a3b$s"));
    }
```

Results:

```
A3D3S2
A1D2S3
A1D1A1S1A1
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a `FOR` loop to go through each character. If the character is in the range of `a-z` or `A-Z` then it is an alphabet. If in the range of `0-9` then it is a digit else special character.

**Code**

```
string inputStr = "a3b$s";
string outputStr = string.Empty;
char firstChar = Convert.ToChar(inputStr.Substring(0, 1));
outputStr = char.IsLetter(firstChar) ? "A1" : char.IsDigit(firstChar) ? "D1" : "S1";
for (int i = 1; i < inputStr.Length; i++)
{
    char nextChar = char.IsLetter(inputStr[i]) ? 'A' : 
                       char.IsDigit(inputStr[i]) ? 'D' : 'S';
    char prevChar = Convert.ToChar(outputStr.Substring(outputStr.Length - 2, 1));
    if (nextChar == prevChar)
    {
        int lastDig = Convert.ToInt32(outputStr.Substring(outputStr.Length - 1, 1));
        outputStr = outputStr.Substring(0, outputStr.Length - 1) + 
                         (lastDig + 1).ToString();
    }
    else
        outputStr += nextChar.ToString() + "1";
}
Console.WriteLine(outputStr.ToString());
```

**Output**

```
A1D1A1S1A1
```

**[Find demo here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/07UZk5)**

Comment: As per the question when i give `a3b$s` as input it should give `A1D1A1S1A1 ` as output but your's is giving `A3D1S1` which is wrong right?

Comment: the order of the string should also be maintained

Comment: @WiXXeY : I have updated my answer. I didn't notice the last scenario properly. Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

With Linq, you can do like this :

```
string myinput = "abc123$%";
            int letter =0 , digit = 0, specialCharacter = 0;
            myinput.ToCharArray().ToList().ForEach(x =>
            {
                letter = Char.IsLetter(x) ? ++letter : letter;
                digit = Char.IsDigit(x) ? ++digit : digit;
                specialCharacter = !Char.IsLetterOrDigit(x) ? 
                                  ++specialCharacter : specialCharacter;
            });
            string formattedVal = String.Format("A{0}D{1}S{2}", letter, digit, 
                                                       specialCharacter);
```

You can directly use array in Linq ForEach without converting to list by :

```
Array.ForEach(myinput.ToCharArray(), x =>
            {
                letter = Char.IsLetter(x) ? ++letter : letter;
                digit = Char.IsDigit(x) ? ++digit : digit;
                specialCharacter = !Char.IsLetterOrDigit(x) ? ++specialCharacter : specialCharacter;
            });
            string formattedVal = String.Format("A{0}D{1}S{2}", letter, digit, specialCharacter);
```

Comment: Same problem as @Ullas's answer - this gives A3D1S1 for the last test case

Comment: exactly @shree.pat18

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
    string s = "a3b$s";
    char etype = 'X'; //current character's type
    char etypeinit = 'X'; //tracker variable - holds type of last character
    string str = "";
    int count = 1;
    foreach(char c in s)
    {
        //Use this block of conditionals to assign type for current character
        if(char.IsLetter(c))
        {
            etype = 'A';
        }
        else if(char.IsDigit(c))
        {
            etype = 'D';
        }
        else
        {
            etype = 'S';
        }

        //This is a different type of character compared to the previous one
        if(etypeinit != etype)
        {
            str += string.Format("{0}{1}",etype,count); //Build the string
            count = 1; //Reset count
        }
        else
        {
            count++; //Increment because this is the same type as previous one
        }
        etypeinit = etype; //Set tracker variable to type of current character

    }

    Console.WriteLine(str);
```

Comment: Output for a34b$s is A1D1A2S1A1 but it should be A1D2A1S1A1

Comment: issue is : Output of "aabfdnas"  is A1, output of "asd233" is A1D3, output of 233ad is D1A2. the first element has always a 1 value.

Answer (score 2):

Little late and little complex but able to produces all expected output as per given inputs in the question, please take a look:

```
string inputString = "abc123$%ab12";

var results = inputString.Select(x => char.IsLetter(x) ? 'A' :
                                     char.IsDigit(x) ? 'D' : 'S');
StringBuilder outPutBuilder = new StringBuilder();
char previousChar = results.First();
int charCount = 0;
foreach (var item in results)
{
    switch (item)
    {
        case 'A':
            if (previousChar == 'A')
            {
                charCount++;
            }
            else
            {
                outPutBuilder.Append(previousChar.ToString() + charCount);
                charCount = 1;
            }
            break;
        case 'D':
            if (previousChar == 'D')               
                charCount++;               
            else
            {
                outPutBuilder.Append(previousChar.ToString() + charCount);
                charCount = 1;
            }
            break;
        default:
            if (previousChar == 'S')
               charCount++;               
            else
            {
                outPutBuilder.Append(previousChar.ToString() + charCount);
                charCount = 1;
            }
            break;
    }
    previousChar = item;
}
outPutBuilder.Append(previousChar.ToString() + charCount);
```

[Working example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/qvC0V2)